# Linear algebra - a unit, U, vector that is perpendicular to u. How many possibilities for U?

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a unit vector u in the direction of v = (3, 4). Find a unit vector U that is
perpendicular to u. How many possibilities for U?

u should be (3/5,4/5) And because of perpendicular to U. So, u dot U = 0.

**The solution is the only perpendicular unit vector would be -U = (4/5, -3/5)**

My question is why it can't be (-4/5, 3/5)

Comment: (-4/5, 3/5) is perpendicular to u, so maybe it's a mistake from your book

Comment: There are two solutions. If $U$ is a solution, then of course $-U$ is also.

Answer (score 2):

Below we can see a plot of the vectors $U=(3,4)$, $u=(\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5})$, $\omega =(-\frac{4}{5}, \frac{3}{5})$ and $w$, where $\omega=-w$. Here we can clearly see, graphically, that:

$$\omega \perp u$$ and

$$w \perp u$$

[image: Plot of the aforementioned vectors]

Computing dot products we can also see that:

$$\omega \cdot u=0$$ and

$$w \cdot u=0$$

So we arrive at the same conclusion. There are two vectors that are perpendicular to $u$ ($\omega$ and $w$), as is always the case with nonzero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and such vectors are always the negatives of each other.